# Connection refused during running app on docker - Spring Boot & mssql server

Tags: java, sql-server, spring, docker, spring-boot

I'm start to play with Docker. I'm trying to run Spring Boot application on Docker which connects with mssql-server-linux on docker. I'm configure and run mssql server. My app has set database port and when I run this app in IntelliJ everything is ok. Also when I build app './mvnw install dockerfile:build' command everything is ok. Also adds entity to database during build. When I try run app 'docker run' command I get this exception:

```
com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: The TCP/IP connection to the host localhost, port 1433 has failed. Error: "Connection refused. Verify the connection properties. Make sure that an instance of SQL Server is running on the host and accepting TCP/IP connections at the port. Make sure that TCP connections to the port are not blocked by a firewall.".
```

What's the problem?

My spring boot app properties:

```
spring.datasource.username=sa
spring.datasource.password=ABCabc123!
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:sqlserver://localhost:1433;databaseName=DockerApp
spring.datasource.driverClassName=com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.show_sql=true
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.format_sql=true
spring.jpa.hibernate.dialect=org.hibernate.dialect.SQLServer2012Dialect
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=update
```

Dockerfile:

```
FROM java:8
VOLUME /tmp
ARG JAR_FILE
COPY ${JAR_FILE} docker-app.jar
ENTRYPOINT ["java","-Djava.security.egd=file:/dev/./urandom","-
jar","/docker-app.jar"]
CMD ["-start"]
```

My build options in pom.xml:

```
<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        </plugin>

        <plugin>
            <groupId>com.spotify</groupId>
            <artifactId>dockerfile-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>1.3.6</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>default</id>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>build</goal>
                        <goal>push</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
            <configuration>
                <repository>my-repo</repository>
                <tag>${project.version}</tag>
                <pullNewerImage>false</pullNewerImage>
                <useMavenSettingsForAuth>true</useMavenSettingsForAuth>
                <buildArgs>
                    <JAR_FILE>target/${project.build.finalName}.jar</JAR_FILE>
                </buildArgs>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

Comment: I'm guessing that localhost is the problem, but I'm not sure.  Can you refer by name or IP address?  https://github.com/moby/moby/issues/25562

Comment: How is MSSQL server is running ? Docker image entry-point is just for Launching the application so Database server must be running before launching this image/container.

Comment: @duffymo you are my boss :D it's working. Thanks a lot :)

Comment: Glad to help.  Good luck with your project.